# Angular ng-repeat dependent on prior ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ngtable, angular-filters

Ive been stuck on this problem for two days now and havent been able to find the right question/example to help me solve the problem.

Basically Im trying to generate a list of categories using ng-repeat and sometimes those categories have subcategories. When a subcategory is present it should appear, and when there is not one it should not appear.

Also, I need these to be generated with <%tr%> tags. (I was able to almost get it to work as needed with the 'GroupBy' directive, but couldnt get it to work with <%tr%> tags).

[http://plnkr.co/edit/0Yjp4B9y0STsm6NZQGBk](http://plnkr.co/edit/0Yjp4B9y0STsm6NZQGBk?p=preview)

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
<tbody >

<tr ng-repeat-start="user in steps | filter:categoryFilter" ng-class="{subcategory:user.SubCategory==1}">
    <td data-title="'Step Name'" ng-class="{textcolorpink:user.SubCategory==1,textcolorblue:user.SubCategory==0}">
        {{user.CategoryName}}
    </td>
    <td data-title="'SubStep'" ng-class="{textcolorwhite:user.SubCategory==0}">
        {{user.CategoryName}}
    </td>

</tr>

<tr ng-repeat-start="subuser in steps | filter:subcategoryFilter" ng-class="{subcategory:subuser.SubCategory==1}">
    <td data-title="'Step Name'" ng-class="{textcolorpink:subuser.SubCategory==1,textcolorblue:subuser.SubCategory==0}">
        {{subuser.CategoryName}}
    </td>
    <td data-title="'SubStep'" ng-class="{textcolorwhite:subuser.SubCategory==0}">
        {{subuser.CategoryName}}
    </td>

</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end ng-hide="true"></tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end ng-hide="true"></tr>

</tbody>
```

This plunker should look something like this:

Main Category 1

-------Subcategory of 1

-------Subcategory of 1

-------Subcategory of 1

Main Category 2

Main Category 3

-------Subcategory of 3

-------Subcategory of 3

-------Subcategory of 3

Main Category 4

Main Category 5

Main Category 6

Main Category 7

Main Category 8

Comment: Sounds like you should be using nested ng-repeats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ng-hide="subuser.MainCategory !== user.index_id"
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/NWL3K7ZMr6qgd9MFWG3N?p=preview

I hope this is what you're looking for.  I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish with all of your code, but this will hide any items that are not a subcategory of the item they're nested within.

If you have options to change your data model, you could nest subCategories within mainCategories.  Nested ng-repeats tend to work very well and it's cleaner than using ng-hide.

Comment: Nailed it! I was trying to do that same type of logic with a filter bit was having trouble-- looks like ng-hide was the ticket- thanks for your help!  Regarding your last statement about nested ng-repeats, I thought that was what I was doing?

Comment: Yes, you are technically doing nested repeats.  But flat data structures don't work as well with ng-repeats (as you have seen). If you can change your structure so the subcategories are children nested within the main categories, ng-repeat takes care of the hiding and everything for you.  Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/iDfEEaDa7FTj44hulpwI?p=preview

Comment: I don't know if that's an option for you, I'm just stating that Angular plays better with that type of structuring.